# Angular2 : click on event target causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, csv, angular, typescript

I want to download a csv file from my angular2 website. For this I get data from a json file. Once the parameters download and href are configurated, I want to simulate a click to launch the download.

However this click cause a infinite loop of download ...
How is it possible to resolve this problem and download only one file ?

Here my component.html code :

```
<div>
    <a class="csv-template" (click)="downloadCSVTemplate($event)">Dowload File</a>
</div>
```

My component.ts code :

```
downloadCSVTemplate(event) {
let locale = this.navContextSrvc.locale;

this.http
    .get('assets/csv/template_'+ locale +'.json')
    .subscribe(res => {
        event.target.download = 'template_'+ locale +'.csv';
        event.target.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'
        + encodeURIComponent(res._body);
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.target.click(); // causes infinite loop of download
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: cause you are calling the function recursively. Everytime you click you call ```downloadCSVTemplate``` and this function triggers a ```click```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you have a click handler that sends another click from within itself? Essentially you've written a function that calls itself without any termination condition. That's an obvious infinite loop that you need to eliminate.

Comment: Why don't you assign proper attributes in your markup?

Comment: I tried by when I click on my link, I download a empty file, because I didn't have time to get my data. That why I wanted to simulate a click at the end. But now I don't how to do

Comment: just avoid calling the click in the same function that the click event calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my async call. The download was launched before that my href attribut changed.

However, because I choose to download files from my client, I just call the file whithout passing by the async call.
With this, the download is launched after my changements

Here the code :

```
downloadCSVTemplate(event) {
    let locale = this.navContextSrvc.locale;
    event.target.download = 'template_'+ locale +'.csv';
    event.target.href = 'assets/csv/template_'+ locale +'.csv';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

`event.target.click(); // causes infinite loop of download`

does not cause an "infinite loop of download", it causes an infinite loop by calling the downloadCSVTemplate over and over.

It's unclear what you are trying to do by calling click() again.